# Calling a String with Multiple Quotation Marks

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am creating a GUI using Python and Tkinter, and I have run into an issue.

There exists a string input, such as 'PP,PKP', and I need to use that input, such as shown the following function:

```
arrivals = model.get_ray_paths(
...     source_depth_in_km=500,
...     distance_in_degree=130,
...     phase_list=["Pdiff", "Sdiff", "pPdiff", "sSdiff"])
```

where in the get_ray_paths function, the phase_list must consist of 1 or more strings that signify the type of seismic phase that you want the ray path for.

My question is, how do I use the input (that the user provides in the GUI), and call those inputs with the appropriate phase_list format, with quotation marks around each phase, and a comma separating each phase?

Currently, the input is set up like this:

```
# Create the Phase Input Box
phasetext = Label(top,text='Input Seismic Phase', fg="black", font=('Helvetica', 16,'bold'))
phasetext.pack(side='top')
global phase
self.phase = StringVar()
self.phase.set('PP')
self.phase_entry = Entry(top, width=10, textvariable=self.phase)
self.phase_entry.pack(side='top')
```

and I call the input in a function like this:

```
def plot_raytrace(self, event=None):
        model = TauPyModel(model="iasp91")
        arrivals = model.get_ray_paths(source_depth_in_km=float(self.depth.get()), distance_in_degree=float(self.deg.get()), phase_list=[self.phase.get()])
        arrivals.plot()
```

If I input only one phase, such as above, 'PP', this works, but if the input is say, 'PKP','PP', I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ray_Trace_Plot.py", line 77, in <module>
    Ray_Trace = Ray_Tracer(root)
  File "Ray_Trace_Plot.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.phase.set('PKP','PP')
TypeError: set() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Any ideas on how to recreate an string input into the format with quotation marks and commas?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `'PKP,PP'`? `'PKP', 'PP'` is two strings.

Comment: Yes, but in the end I need the function get_ray_paths to have the input for the phase list as phase_list=["Pdiff", "Sdiff", "pPdiff", "sSdiff"])

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `split()` function of a string. To make a list of strings from a string with commas as the delimiter:

```
In [1]: 'PKP,PP'.split(',')
Out[1]: ['PKP', 'PP']

In [2]: 'Pdiff,Sdiff,pPdiff,sSdiff'.split(',')
Out[2]: ['Pdiff', 'Sdiff', 'pPdiff', 'sSdiff']
```